# how to replace part of a string in string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, replace, nsstring, str-replace

i want to replace a string in a string. let me explain you what my exacvt aim is.

This ist my String

```
<p>Hello Webseite i want to replace<p>thisPTag</p>which is in the middle 
of the word or in the end of the sentence</p>.
```

If i use

```
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@"|break|"];
```

it replaces only the first 



. But i want to replace **ALL p tags**, doesnt matter if in the sentence or not, white space before or after that also doesnt matter.
**So how can i do that?**

Not really important but good to know:
please keep in mind that i dont want to strip html, i just want to replace the p-tag to set breaks there for correct SSML and TTS(textto speech)

Comment: There's something else going on in your program that you haven't included.  When I try your code it displays...

**|break|Hello Webseite i want to replace|break|thisPTag</p>which is in the middle of the word or in the end of the sentence</p>.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works (all `<p>` are replaced). You probably just confusing `<p>` and `</p>`. These are different literals, so they would have to be replaced separately:

```
NSString * a = @"<p>Hello Webseite i want to replace<p>thisPTag</p>which is in the middle of the word or in the end of the sentence</p>. ";

NSString * b = [a stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@"|break|"];
b =  [b stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@"|break|"];

NSLog(@"%@",b);
```

This prints:

> |break|Hello Webseite i want to replace|break|thisPTag|break|which is in the middle of the word or in the end of the sentence|break|.